# Calling a function from another file in Python

Tags: python, function, class

Yes, this question has been asked before. No, it did not answer my question satisfactorily.
So, I'm creating my Giraffe Program in Python first (don't ask) and I'm trying to get the user to name their giraffe.

My files are all in one package called `code`. In the file `Main_Code`, the function `createGiraffe` is called from `code.Various_Functions`. Here is my code.

```
import code
print("Welcome to The Animal Kingdom.")
userGiraffe = code.Various_Functions.createGiraffe()
```

And the code in code.Giraffes:

```
import code
def createGiraffe():
    print("Name your giraffe.")
    GiraffeName = input()
    return GiraffeName
```

However, when I run Main_Code, it gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jonathan\Documents\Aptana Studio 3 Workspace\The Animal Kingdom\src\code\Main_Code.py", line 3, in <module>
    userGiraffe = code.Giraffes.Giraffes.createGiraffe()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Giraffes'
```

How do I fix this? I believe that I've done everything by the book. It's all using the same package so I can call the function, I'm calling it from the right place, and the function has no syntax errors. Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Why is the code in the traceback different to the code you have put in your question? One is `code.Various_Functions.createGiraffe()`, the other is `code.Giraffes.Giraffes.createGiraffe()`. And why not just `code.Giraffes.createGiraffe()`?

Comment: Yeah, that was a messup. I copied the wrong error. The traceback should be code.Various_Functions.createGiraffe() which does create the same exact error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do

```
import code.Giraffes
```

before executing the offending line:

```
userGiraffe = code.Giraffes.Giraffes.createGiraffe()
```

Comment: Shouldn't importing "code" do all the work for that? Or do I have to import Giraffe separately also?

Comment: You have to import submodules separately. Try in IDLE: `import os` `os.path.join("this","shouldn't","work")`, then `import os.path` and `os.path.join("This","should","work")`

Comment: I see. Also, that was a mess-up with the error. I copied the error before I changed it to Various_Functions (which makes the same error).

Comment: @JonathanSpirit No, you need to import submodules separately.

Comment: I'm glad to know it was helpful. Please accept the answer as correct if you are happy with it.

Comment: I can't for six minutes. But I will.

Answer (score 0):

When you call function like:

```
userGiraffe = code.Giraffes.Giraffes.createGiraffe()
```

it means you have a project in dir `code` with internal dir `Giraffes` and module `Giraffes` with function `createGiraffe`. Is this your exception?

Comment: "code" is my package. In it is the file "Giraffes" with the class "Giraffes" with the function "createGiraffe".